# Angular return URL is wrong

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-routing, url-parsing

In my Angular 5 Application I am doing something like this at

this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl']

I am using this when a user accesses a route but it's not logged in. He is redirected to the login page and after login he should be going back to this return url.

The problem is that http://localhost:4200/schedule?selectedDate=2018-01-29 when accessing this route, the return url becomes:

http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fschedule%3FselectedDate%3D2018-01-29 and after the successful login, the application tries to go to the http://localhost:4200/%2Fschedule%3FselectedDate%3D2018-01-29 URL but that throws a 404 error since it does not recognize the path.

Any idea how can I stop Angular changing my url to this format ? I was assuming that it would pick up the correct URL.

Comment: see my modified answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to somehow fix this by instead of using

```
this.router.navigate(this.returnUrl)
```

I used

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
```

Comment: Did not think that would be the issue since all the navigation in the app is done in the first way.

Answer (score 0):

i think You can simply add the url like this `<button class="btn btn-md btn-danger pull-right" routerLink="../../">cancel</button>`
or else call click event

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
this.returnUrl = decodeURIComponent(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl']);
```

Comment: I changed it to this, I was assuming this is what I was supposed to do, but the result is the same, on the login component the URL looks like 
http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fschedule%3FselectedDate%3D2018-01-29 and after logging in it looks like 
http://localhost:4200/schedule%3FselectedDate%3D2018-01-29. 

I think I might need to do the decoding somewhere else.